# Imporxml is not price the data getting syntax error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importxml

importxml is working fine with manual insert but while updating with funtions getting syntax error. Kindly help me.. how to convert string to actual query.

```
function Getdata() {
```

var Technicals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Techinical");
var queryString = Math.random();

var oilindicators='=IMPORTXML("http://www.investing.com/commodities/crude-oil-technical","//*[@id='last_last']")';
Technicals.getRange('a1').setValue(oilindicators);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Please escape single quotes in `IMPORTXML()`.
- When the formula is imported, please use `setFormula()`.

#### From :

```
var oilindicators='=IMPORTXML("http://www.investing.com/commodities/crude-oil-technical","//*[@id='last_last']")';
Technicals.getRange('a1').setValue(oilindicators);
```

#### To :

```
var oilindicators = '=IMPORTXML("http://www.investing.com/commodities/crude-oil-technical","//*[@id=\'last_last\']")'; // Modification
Technicals.getRange('a1').setFormula(oilindicators); // Modification
```

#### Reference :

- [setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: The above query worked for me. I one more help is it possible to covert the xml import cell to text not with xml formulas.

Comment: @Murali Pujari I'm sorry. For your next question, I couldn't understand what you want to do. So can you post it with the detail information and samples as a new question? By this, many users including me can think of your solution. If my this proposal is what you don't want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need to know who to change the xml fetch data to text that means content only--- should not be formulas only the text

Comment: Sorry Tanaike,  I have posted question. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115231/importxml-convert-content-only/115237#115237

Comment: @Murali Pujari Thank you for your response.