# Importxml convert content only

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

I am getting the price value from the website. I would like to make the value as static(remove formulas) to prevent auto refresh in sheet due to that the price values will change-- I don't want it.  kindy help me how to change the content only the price not with below xml formulas.

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.investing.com/commodities/crude-oil-technical#'+n+'","//*[@id=\'last_last\']")'`

Answer (score 0):

Use copy and then paste value only.

Perhaps it will be even more easy to copy the desired value directly from the web page than writing a formula then doing copy & paste as value the result.